# google-app-engine: querying a String property in Model doesn't retrieves result

Tags: google-app-engine, gql

I have a Model represented as

```
class Suggestion(db.Model):
    text = db.TextProperty()
    votes = db.IntegerProperty()
    time_added = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    time_modified = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

and I added a Suggestion as

```
suggestion = Suggestion(text='Adding Suggestion', votes=1)
suggestion.put()
```

I see that that the value is inserted, now I want to get this suggestion by querying the text property. I did the following

```
from models import Suggestion
suggestion = Suggestion.all().filter('text = ', 'Adding Suggestion').fetch(1)[0]
print suggestion
```

The result is empty. How can I make this query work?

Thank you

Comment: In addition to lucemia's correct answer, note that `.get()` is a shorter and less error-prone alternative to `.fetch(1)[0]`.

Comment: ah, thanks Nick, I didn't know about it, I will use it

Comment: Don't forget to vote up and select lucemia's answer as correct if it answers your question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is due to the text property cannot be used in filters.
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#TextProperty

> Unlike StringProperty, a TextProperty value can be more than 500
> characters long. However, TextProperty values are not indexed, and
> cannot be used in filters or sort orders

There are some alternative ways to do so.

1. If the "text" shorter than 500 characters, then you may use StringProperty. StringProperty can be used in filter.
2. Try the 3rd party full text search approaches for google app engine.
   http://code.google.com/p/guestbook-example-appengine-full-text-search/
3. App engine team is working on providing The full text search function in near future.
   http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2012/01/happy-birthday-high-replication.html

## Edit

the full text functin is developed by google app engine team:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview